# Encounter classdefnotfound error for reactivetransactionmanager class after upgrading spring-fox swagger to Open-api doc

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am trying to upgrade from swagger spring-fox to open-api in a spring-boot application and I am encountering below error.

**caused by java.lang.noclassdeffounderror org/springframework/transaction/reactivetransactionmanager**. I tried adding implementation 'org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.4.RELEASE' in gradle but after adding that I see **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager** which did not solve by adding implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.2.4.RELEASE'. Can someone suggest on how we can resolve this? I am using folowwing versions

implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.1.9.RELEASE"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.9.RELEASE"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.1.9.RELEASE"
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.14'
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.2.5.RELEASE"
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.4.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.2.4.RELEASE'

Answer (score 0):

Goodnight friend,

- according to the documentation, https://springdoc.org/#what-is-the-compatibility-matrix-of-springdoc-openapi-with-spring-boot , springdoc-openapi-ui should be compatible with Spring Boot 2.6.x.
- however, it loads spring-boot 2.7.0, overwrites the version specified in the project and makes it incompatible with many other spring dependencies still in 2.6.x versions
- this causes exceptions like the one below at startup:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding below dependency fix the issue. Please use the version which suitable.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.ReactiveTransactionManager

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.31</version>
 </dependency>
```